# Is there a way to load a (PlantUML-) generated image, without saving to the file system?

Tags: java, image, file, serialization, plantuml

I'm working with the Plant UML API to generate UML diagrams of tests in my Java project. The API generates an image and saves it to a PNG or SVG file in the file system.

I'm wondering if there's a way to just load the image directly in the console without saving it to the file system (or loading a file already in the file system).

For reference, I'm using the documentation PUML provided [here](https://plantuml.com/api) and I'm calling something like:

```
import net.sourceforge.plantuml.SourceStringReader;
OutputStream png = ...;
String source = "@startuml\n";
source += "Bob -> Alice : hello\n";
source += "@enduml\n";

SourceStringReader reader = new SourceStringReader(source);
// Write the first image to "png"
String desc = reader.outputImage(png).getDescription();
// Return a null string if no generation
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should do the job.

```java
public byte[] createUmlImage(String source){
    try {
        SourceStringReader reader = new SourceStringReader(source);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        reader.outputImage(os);
        return os.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I would also make another suggestion. Make use of `StringBuilder`'s `append()` for string concatenation instead of the `+` operator.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think it worked though :( I'm running it in Eclipse and nothing pops up sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell, something like this will work:

```
  open -a Firefox <(plantuml -p -tsvg "$puml_file_path")
```

the -p option sends the output to stdout, and the <(...) notation is process substitution.